# How to manipulate DOM in ubuntu command line without actually rendering the page on the GUI?

Tags: linux, firefox, cron, javascript, firefox-developer-tools

I've written a small JS snippet which clicks some buttons in the DOM of a certain target website in a loop.
To run this snippet, I open the target website in firefox. Then I paste this JS snippet in the console and let it do its job. PFA a sample snippet below.

Now the problem is that I want to automate this whole process to avoid actually opening firefox everyday. I would just like to write a cron to do this daily and everything should happen in background. I need to deploy this on a cloud linux VM without a GUI.

Any ideas about how I should proceed?
(I already know that I can use the website's backend API, thereby bypassing the entire DOM manipulation. But I would like to explore other options.)

P.S.: Sample of a code that I enter into the firefox's developer tools console:

```
func = setInterval(function () {
    // Some button that I want to click.
    document.evaluate("/html/body/div[1]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click();

    // TODO: A break condition (or not)
}, 6000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to abandon what you have been doing so far, and learn to use [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Selenium is pretty much industry standard, when we are testing web apps, and allows you to automate (script) browser interaction.

> Selenium automates browsers. That's it! What you do with that power is
>   entirely up to you. Primarily, it is for automating web applications
>   for testing purposes, but is certainly not limited to just that.
>   Boring web-based administration tasks can (and should!) be automated
>   as well.
>
> Selenium has the support of some of the largest browser vendors who
>   have taken (or are taking) steps to make Selenium a native part of
>   their browser. It is also the core technology in countless other
>   browser automation tools, APIs and frameworks.